# Android, read content from URL in 3.1?

Tags: android, url

I have this function which works fine in 2.3, but it fails in 3.1

Any ideas?

```
public static String readUrl( String url2 ){
    String str = "";
    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL( url2 );

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        str = in.readLine();
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return str;
}
```

02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:69)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:48)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1038)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:523)
02-02 21:58:09.100: E/AndroidRuntime(30937):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)

Answer (score 2):

Since Honeycomb, you have to do network operations asynchronously (NOT on the UI-thread). For instance, you could use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). More on asynchronous operations can be found here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

If you do your network operations asynchronously your interface will be [more responsive](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) and you don't risk to cause an ANR dialog.